# How to make new windows appear at center of the screen in JavaFX?

Tags: window, javafx, javafx-2

Am doing a project in JavaFX. Each window of my project has variable sizes. While running the project, the first window appears at the center of the screen. This is the screen shot.

[image]

But when I move to next page its size is different and so it appears like -

[image]

As you can see this window appeared to the right side of the screen. But I need to display every new window appear at the center of the screen. How can I do it ?

Comment: use `stage.centerOnScreen();` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702191/center-location-of-stage

Comment: @AnshulParashar I open each new window using this code -    if (usr1.equals(username) && pwd.equals(password)) {
                ((Stage) btn.getScene().getWindow()).setScene(new Scene(
                        new TutorPage()));      So how will I use 'stage.centerOnScreen();' here ?

Comment: `(Stage) btn.getScene().getWindow().centerOnScreen();`

Comment: @AnshulParashar Should I use this instead of ' (Stage) btn.getScene().getWindow()).setScene(new Scene( new TutorPage())); '  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you use this code;

```
yourScene.getWindow().centerOnScreen();
```

or

```
((Stage)(sceneObject.getScene.getWindow())).centerOnScreen();
```

> sceneObject is any object which is in your scene.